# Как передвинуть камеру вперёд?

Tags: unity3d

Надо передвинуть камеру вперёд по нажатию на кнопку, но у камеры есть rotation, и из-за этого я никак не могу это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтоы понять, куда смотрит объект (то есть получить тот самый перед, куда нужно сдвинуть камеру) вы можете использовать gameObject.transform.forward
Для самого сдвига можно использовать разные пути: сдвиг в Update (как предложил @RiotBr3aker в первом ответе), с помощью Vector3.MoveTowards, Vector3.Lerp и т.д.

Если вы хотите двигать камеру быстрее (или медленнее), чем она двигается с помощью transform.forward, то можно умножать это на speed. После чего можно поиграться с этой переменной speed, найдя оптимальную скорость.

Comment: Я, конечно, извиняюсь, но чем ваш ответ отличается от моего?

Comment: Во-первых, здравствуйте. Наши ответы похожи, хотя есть и отличия: вы упомянули про вектора transform.right, transform.up, умножение их на -1 и т.д., а я привел примеры как еще можно передвигать объект кроме изменения transform и Update. Мне кажется, что два ответа на вопрос дают тому, кто его задал больше информации, поэтому я написал свой ответ. Хотя я думал, что автор вопроса выберет ваш ответ лучшим (как минимум, потому что вы ответили раньше), а мой ответ просто отметит стрелкой вверх, автор решил сделать наоборот. Я, разумеется, никак на его мнение не влиял (да и не могу никак повлиять)

Comment: В вашем ответе кроме Update нет других вариантов, два упомянутых метода - лишь альтернатива знаку плюса. Даже аналог параметра "speed" есть в моем ответе, от чего и возник вопрос, чем ваш ответ отличается от моего, если он не даёт никакой новой информации.

Comment: К сожалению, я никак не могу повлиять на выбор автора вопроса. Сейчас, когда лучший ответ уже выбран, поменять его невозможно, так что продолжать дальнейшую дискуссию бессмысленно

Comment: А какое отношение принятый ответ имеет к тому, что вы переписали чужой ответ?

Comment: Я написал (не переписал) свой ответ. Он не совпадает с вашим. Я добавил свое. В вашем ответе есть свое. В любом случае 2 ответа для автора вопроса лучше, чем 1. Какое отношение имеет правильный ответ? Я так понимаю, что вы злитесь именно из-за того, что ваш ответ не выбрали правильным. Сейчас уже невозможно ничего изменить, поэтому на дальнейшие ваши сообщения отвечать я не вижу смысла. Давайте закончим дискуссию:)

Comment: А вообще у вас на странице написано, что вы прекратили деятельность на русском stack overflow, но со мной вы почему-то все спорите. То, что вы прекратили деятельность на этом сайте дает мне еще один повод закончить дискуссию (надеюсь мирно). Больше, пожалуйста, не пишите - отвечать я все равно не буду. Я не злюсь, просто ваши сообщения отзываются надоевшими уведомлениями.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте свойство `Transform.forward`, чтобы получить **зависимый** от поворота нормализованный вектор-направление "вперед":

```
public float Length;

private void Update() {
    transform.position += transform.forward * Length * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

P.S.
У `Transform` есть right/up вектора, чтобы получить противоположные back/left/down вектора, нужно использовать первые 3 со знаком минуса, например: `var leftDir = -right;`